# Alert monitor trigger an azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I have some alerts that trigger an c# azure function, problem..
i can't get the alert on request body of the AF. Should't i be able to parse the body and check the alert name for instance?

I managed to trigger an logic app and check the content of the alert, but with the AF, is killing me.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Here's how i tried to parse the body and always print's nothing.. that's why i'm thinking that is acting different than the logic app trigger.

```
var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        log.LogInformation($"contentmessage:", content);
        
        string body = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
        log.LogInformation($"bodymessage: {body}", req.Scheme);

        
            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body);
            log.LogInformation($"message: {obj.data.context.name}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, please change the code in your function from:

```
log.LogInformation($"contentmessage:", content);
```

to

```
log.LogInformation("contentmessage:{$content}", content);
```

or print the `content` directly:

```
log.LogInformation(content);
```

Comment: Thanks.. what a silly silly mistake.. i've already wondered on doing that but did with a different object not the content. I seriosly thought that the parameteres were printed also as properties or so.. but well. Thank you